# generate extract number of thumbnails with ffmpeg from a video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to get extract number of thumbnails for a video with ffmpeg for example 5-6 how can I do that?

the following command will generate 1 i would like 5-6
`shell_exec("ffmpeg -ss 01:23:45 -i input.mkv -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg");`

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: for generating thumbnails I don't have any other code still looking how do that

Comment: like you do that one repeat it 5..6 time ..

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
for($thum = 1; $thum <= 5; $thum++)
    {
        $count = $thum * 10;
        shell_exec("ffmpeg -ss $count -i video.mkv -vframes 1 -q:v 2 $thum.jpg");
    }
```